# Read framework laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have read framework Laravel but I found 3 versions of Laravel: 5, 6 and 7. What is the best and more used version? And what version do you recommend for developers to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `LTS` releases, such as `Laravel 5.5`, bug fixes are provided for 2 years and security fixes are provided for 3 years. These releases provide the longest window of support and maintenance. For general releases, bug fixes are provided for 6 months and security fixes are provided for 1 year.

---

- **5.5 LTS**  *Released on* August 30, 2017
- **6 LTS** *Released on* September 3, 2019
- **7 Non LTS, Current Stable** *Released on* March 3, 2020

---

As with almost any other software, you should go with the LTS or latest version of the framework. That way, you will have as much as possible bugs fixed, long-term support, security updates, and most importantly cool new features.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve, take a look at the laravel 7 release notes to see if there is any changes in there that is worth your reason to choose ^7.

At this point in time it is not really wise to choose version ^5 or its LTS(5.5) as it would not be supported after august as per the documentation [laravel 7 release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/releases), You could go with most current LTS version 6 as it is the long term version (LTS) and is going to be supported till 2022.

But as I said earlier it also depends on what you are trying to achieve and if you have enough time as is maybe you could begin with 5.5 and then move on but if you are really wanting to start using laravel to build your apps now. Then I would suggest you go with version 6 as it is the latest LTS version and would receive long term security updates and patches till 2022.